# In Java, Hibernate and MySQL, ñ equals to n

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, utf

I have a table which has some varchars columns. We are using Hibernate and MySQL.

The problem arise when MySQL compares and matchs `N` with `Ñ`; I have seem solutions in `MYSQL` in other `SO post` like

```
SELECT FIRST_NAME 
FROM CONTACT 
WHERE FIRST_NAME LIKE '%ñ%' COLLATE utf8_spanish_ci
```

and

```
SELECT FIRST_NAME FROM CONTACT WHERE FIRST_NAME LIKE BINARY '%ñ%'
```

I was wondering how I could do this in Hibernate by query basis. I mean write a Criteria which not matches `N` and `Ñ` without do so much on the engine MySQL. Is this possible like using `BINARY` or using `COLLATE` in Hibernate as parameter, or any other workaround?

### Update

I have try this code

```
private final Student test(final int id)
{
    return (Student)currentSession().createCriteria(Student.class)
          .add(Restrictions.idEq(id))
          .add(Restrictions.ilike("c01","n",MatchMode.ANYWHERE))
          .uniqueResult();    
}
```

My table has `a row with id=26 and c01='ñlk'`, and I have set this in `hibernate.cfg`:

```
 <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/database?connectionCollation=utf8_spanish_ci</property>
```

I have test the code with

```
    final Student student = clazz.test(26);
    System.out.println("results: "+(student==null?"NULO":("ID: "+student.getId()+" c01: "+student.getC01())));
```

but still is returning results:

```
results: ID: 26 c01: ñlk
```

I was hoping not returning results but still are considering `N` and `Ñ` equals.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

You can try to set the collation at jdbc connection level.
In the place where you define the connection url:

jdbc:mysql://[host:port]/[database][?propertyName1][=propertyValue1]

try this property: connectionCollation=utf8_spanish_ci

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/en/connector-j-reference-configuration-properties.html

I hope to be helpful.

Comment: i will try it is it works i mark as resolved thanks.

Comment: @chiperortiz I tested it in a MYSQL database and it is useless :( I think the only way is to add collation to SELECTs